# Java and GUI - Where do ActionListeners belong according to MVC pattern?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, model-view-controller, awt

I'm currently writing a template Java application and somehow, I'm not sure about where the ActionListeners belong if I wanted to cleanly follow the MVC pattern.

The example is Swing based, but it's not about the framework but rather the basic concept of MVC in Java, using any framework to create GUI.

I started with an absolutely simple application containing a JFrame and a JButton (to dispose the frame hence close the application). The code trailing this post. Nothing really special, just to clearify what we're talking about. I didn't start with the Model yet as this question was bugging me too much.

There has already been more than one similar question(s), like these:
[MVC pattern with many ActionListeners](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20620167/mvc-pattern-with-many-actionlisteners)
[Java swing - Where should the ActionListener go?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14179485/java-swing-where-should-the-actionlistener-go)

But non of them was really satisfying as I'd like to know two things:

- Is it reasonable to have all ActionListeners in a separate package?

  - I'd like to do so for the sake of readability of View and Controller, esp. if there's a lot of listeners
- How would I execute a Controller function from within an ActionListener, if the listener is not a sub class inside the Controller? (follow-up question)

I hope this is not too general or vague I'm asking here, but it makes me think for a while now. I always used sort of **my own way, letting the ActionHandler know about the Controller**, but this does not seem right, so I'd finally like to know how this is done properly.

Kind regards,
jaySon

---

Controller:

```
package controller;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import view.MainView;

public class MainController
{
    MainView mainView = new MainView();

    public MainController()
    {
        this.initViewActionListeners();
    }

    private void initViewActionListeners()
    {
        mainView.initButtons(new CloseListener());
    }

    public class CloseListener implements ActionListener
    {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            mainView.dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

View:

```
package view;

import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class MainView extends JFrame
{
    JButton button_close    = new JButton();
    JPanel  panel_mainPanel = new JPanel();

    private static final long   serialVersionUID    = 5791734712409634055L;

    public MainView()
    {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setSize(500, 500);
        this.add(panel_mainPanel);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public void initButtons(ActionListener actionListener)
    {
        this.button_close = new JButton("Close");
        this.button_close.setSize(new Dimension(100, 20));
        this.button_close.addActionListener(actionListener);
        this.panel_mainPanel.add(button_close);
    }
}
```

Comment: They belong to the view layer. No action listener should be defined outside of views.

Comment: That's strange though as to my understanding an action listener should call Controller functions as the view should not have any "functionality" as a Service class might have.

Comment: @jaySon But the controller should have NO UI logic either ;)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

That's a very difficult question to answer with Swing, as Swing is not a pure MVC implementation, the view and controller are mixed.

Technically, a model and controller should be able to interact and the controller and view should be able to interact, but the view and model should never interact, which clearly isn't how Swing works, but that's another debate...

Another issue is, you really don't want to expose UI components to anybody, the controller shouldn't care how certain actions occur, only that they can.

This would suggest that the `ActionListener`s attached to your UI controls should be maintained by the view.  The view should then alert the controller that some kind of action has occurred.  For this, you could use another `ActionListener`, managed by the view, to which the controller subscribes to.

Better yet, I would have a dedicated view listener, which described the actions that this view might produce, for example...

```
public interface MainViewListener {
    public void didPerformClose(MainView mainView);
}
```

The controller would then subscribe to the view via this listener and the view would call `didPerformClose` when (in this case) the close button is pressed.

Even in this example, I would be tempted to make a "main view" interface, which described the properties (setters and getters) and actions (listeners/callbacks) that any implementation is guaranteed to provide, then you don't care how these actions occur, only that when they do, you are expected to do something...

At each level you want to ask yourself, how easy would it be to change any element (change the model or the controller or the view) for another instance?  If you find yourself having to decouple the code, then you have a problem.  Communicate via interfaces and try and reduce the amount of coupling between the layers and the amount that each layer knows about the others to the point where they are simply maintaining contracts

**Updated...**

Let's take this for an example...

[image: Login]

There are actually two views (discounting the actual dialog), there is the credentials view and the login view, yes they are different as you will see.

## CredentialsView

The credentials view is responsible for collecting the details that are to be authenticated, the user name and password.  It will provide information to the controller to let it know when those credentials have been changed, as the controller may want to take some action, like enabling the "login" button...

The view will also want to know when authentication is about to take place, as it will want to disable it's fields, so the user can't update the view while the authentication is taking place, equally, it will need to know when the authentication fails or succeeds, as it will need to take actions for those eventualities.

```
public interface CredentialsView {

    public String getUserName();
    public char[] getPassword();

    public void willAuthenticate();
    public void authenticationFailed();
    public void authenticationSucceeded();

    public void setCredentialsViewController(CredentialsViewController listener);

}

public interface CredentialsViewController {

    public void credientialsDidChange(CredentialsView view);

}
```

### CredentialsPane

The `CredentialsPane` is the physical implementation of a `CredentialsView`, it implements the contract, but manages it's own internal state.  How the contract is managed is irrelevent to the controller, it only cares about the contract been upheld...

```
public class CredentialsPane extends JPanel implements CredentialsView {

    private CredentialsViewController controller;

    private JTextField userNameField;
    private JPasswordField passwordField;

    public CredentialsPane(CredentialsViewController controller) {
        setCredentialsViewController(controller);
        setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        userNameField = new JTextField(20);
        passwordField = new JPasswordField(20);

        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        gbc.insets = new Insets(2, 2, 2, 2);
        gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.EAST;
        add(new JLabel("Username: "), gbc);

        gbc.gridy++;
        add(new JLabel("Password: "), gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 1;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        add(userNameField, gbc);
        gbc.gridy++;
        add(passwordField, gbc);

        DocumentListener listener = new DocumentListener() {
            @Override
            public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
                getCredentialsViewController().credientialsDidChange(CredentialsPane.this);
            }

            @Override
            public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
                getCredentialsViewController().credientialsDidChange(CredentialsPane.this);
            }

            @Override
            public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
                getCredentialsViewController().credientialsDidChange(CredentialsPane.this);
            }
        };

        userNameField.getDocument().addDocumentListener(listener);
        passwordField.getDocument().addDocumentListener(listener);

    }

    @Override
    public CredentialsViewController getCredentialsViewController() {
        return controller;
    }

    @Override
    public String getUserName() {
        return userNameField.getText();
    }

    @Override
    public char[] getPassword() {
        return passwordField.getPassword();
    }

    @Override
    public void willAuthenticate() {
        userNameField.setEnabled(false);
        passwordField.setEnabled(false);
    }

    @Override
    public void authenticationFailed() {
        userNameField.setEnabled(true);
        passwordField.setEnabled(true);

        userNameField.requestFocusInWindow();
        userNameField.selectAll();

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Authentication has failed", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }

    @Override
    public void authenticationSucceeded() {
        // Really don't care, but you might want to stop animation, for example...
    }

    public void setCredentialsViewController(CredentialsViewController controller){
        this.controller = controller;
    }

}
```

## LoginView

The `LoginView` is responsible for managing a `CredentialsView`, but also for notifying the `LoginViewController` when authentication should take place or if the process was cancelled by the user, via some means...

Equally, the `LoginViewController` will tell the view when authentication is about to take place and if the authentication failed or was successful.

```
public interface LoginView {

    public CredentialsView getCredentialsView();

    public void willAuthenticate();
    public void authenticationFailed();
    public void authenticationSucceeded();

    public void dismissView();

    public LoginViewController getLoginViewController();

}

public interface LoginViewController {

    public void authenticationWasRequested(LoginView view);
    public void loginWasCancelled(LoginView view);

}
```

### LoginPane

The `LoginPane` is kind of special, it is acting as the view for the `LoginViewController`, but it is also acting as the controller for the `CredentialsView`. This is important, as there is nothing saying that a view can't be a controller, but I would be careful about how you implement such things, as it might not always make sense to do it this way, but because the two views are working together to gather information and manage events, it made sense in this case.

Because the `LoginPane` will need to change it's own state based on the changes in the `CredentialsView`, it makes sense to allow the `LoginPane` to act as the controller in this case, otherwise, you'd need to supply more methods that controlled that state of the buttons, but this starts to bleed UI logic over to the controller...

```
public static class LoginPane extends JPanel implements LoginView, CredentialsViewController {

    private LoginViewController controller;
    private CredentialsPane credientialsView;

    private JButton btnAuthenticate;
    private JButton btnCancel;

    private boolean wasAuthenticated;

    public LoginPane(LoginViewController controller) {
        setLoginViewController(controller);
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        setBorder(new EmptyBorder(8, 8, 8, 8));

        btnAuthenticate = new JButton("Login");
        btnCancel = new JButton("Cancel");

        JPanel buttons = new JPanel();
        buttons.add(btnAuthenticate);
        buttons.add(btnCancel);

        add(buttons, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        credientialsView = new CredentialsPane(this);
        add(credientialsView);

        btnAuthenticate.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                getLoginViewController().authenticationWasRequested(LoginPane.this);
            }
        });
        btnCancel.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                getLoginViewController().loginWasCancelled(LoginPane.this);
                // I did think about calling dispose here,
                // but's not really the the job of the cancel button to decide what should happen here...
            }
        });

        validateCreientials();

    }

    public static boolean showLoginDialog(LoginViewController controller) {

        final LoginPane pane = new LoginPane(controller);

        JDialog dialog = new JDialog();
        dialog.setTitle("Login");
        dialog.setModal(true);
        dialog.add(pane);
        dialog.pack();
        dialog.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        dialog.setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
        dialog.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
                pane.getLoginViewController().loginWasCancelled(pane);
            }
        });
        dialog.setVisible(true);

        return pane.wasAuthenticated();

    }

    public boolean wasAuthenticated() {
        return wasAuthenticated;
    }

    public void validateCreientials() {

        CredentialsView view = getCredentialsView();
        String userName = view.getUserName();
        char[] password = view.getPassword();
        if ((userName != null && userName.trim().length() > 0) && (password != null && password.length > 0)) {

            btnAuthenticate.setEnabled(true);

        } else {

            btnAuthenticate.setEnabled(false);

        }

    }

    @Override
    public void dismissView() {
        SwingUtilities.windowForComponent(this).dispose();
    }

    @Override
    public CredentialsView getCredentialsView() {
        return credientialsView;
    }

    @Override
    public void willAuthenticate() {
        getCredentialsView().willAuthenticate();
        btnAuthenticate.setEnabled(false);
    }

    @Override
    public void authenticationFailed() {
        getCredentialsView().authenticationFailed();
        validateCreientials();
        wasAuthenticated = false;
    }

    @Override
    public void authenticationSucceeded() {
        getCredentialsView().authenticationSucceeded();
        validateCreientials();
        wasAuthenticated = true;
    }

    public LoginViewController getLoginViewController() {
        return controller;
    }

    public void setLoginViewController(LoginViewController controller) {
        this.controller = controller;
    }

    @Override
    public void credientialsDidChange(CredentialsView view) {
        validateCreientials();
    }

}
```

## Working example

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JPasswordField;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.event.DocumentEvent;
import javax.swing.event.DocumentListener;
import sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection;

public class Test {

    protected static final Random AUTHENTICATION_ORACLE = new Random();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public interface CredentialsView {
        public String getUserName();
        public char[] getPassword();
        public void willAuthenticate();
        public void authenticationFailed();
        public void authenticationSucceeded();
        public CredentialsViewController getCredentialsViewController();
    }

    public interface CredentialsViewController {
        public void credientialsDidChange(CredentialsView view);
    }

    public interface LoginView {
        public CredentialsView getCredentialsView();
        public void willAuthenticate();
        public void authenticationFailed();
        public void authenticationSucceeded();
        public void dismissView();
        public LoginViewController getLoginViewController();
    }

    public interface LoginViewController {
        public void authenticationWasRequested(LoginView view);
        public void loginWasCancelled(LoginView view);
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                LoginViewController controller = new LoginViewController() {

                    @Override
                    public void authenticationWasRequested(LoginView view) {
                        view.willAuthenticate();
                        LoginAuthenticator authenticator = new LoginAuthenticator(view);
                        authenticator.authenticate();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void loginWasCancelled(LoginView view) {

                        view.dismissView();

                    }
                };

                if (LoginPane.showLoginDialog(controller)) {

                    System.out.println("You shell pass");

                } else {

                    System.out.println("You shell not pass");

                }

                System.exit(0);

            }
        });
    }

    public class LoginAuthenticator {

        private LoginView view;

        public LoginAuthenticator(LoginView view) {
            this.view = view;
        }

        public void authenticate() {

            Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(2000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                        Logger.getLogger(Test.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                    }
                    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            if (AUTHENTICATION_ORACLE.nextBoolean()) {
                                view.authenticationSucceeded();
                                view.dismissView();
                            } else {
                                view.authenticationFailed();
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
            t.start();

        }

    }

    public static class LoginPane extends JPanel implements LoginView, CredentialsViewController {

        private LoginViewController controller;
        private CredentialsPane credientialsView;

        private JButton btnAuthenticate;
        private JButton btnCancel;

        private boolean wasAuthenticated;

        public LoginPane(LoginViewController controller) {
            setLoginViewController(controller);
            setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            setBorder(new EmptyBorder(8, 8, 8, 8));

            btnAuthenticate = new JButton("Login");
            btnCancel = new JButton("Cancel");

            JPanel buttons = new JPanel();
            buttons.add(btnAuthenticate);
            buttons.add(btnCancel);

            add(buttons, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

            credientialsView = new CredentialsPane(this);
            add(credientialsView);

            btnAuthenticate.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    getLoginViewController().authenticationWasRequested(LoginPane.this);
                }
            });
            btnCancel.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    getLoginViewController().loginWasCancelled(LoginPane.this);
                    // I did think about calling dispose here,
                    // but's not really the the job of the cancel button to decide what should happen here...
                }
            });

            validateCreientials();

        }

        public static boolean showLoginDialog(LoginViewController controller) {

            final LoginPane pane = new LoginPane(controller);

            JDialog dialog = new JDialog();
            dialog.setTitle("Login");
            dialog.setModal(true);
            dialog.add(pane);
            dialog.pack();
            dialog.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            dialog.setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
            dialog.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
                    pane.getLoginViewController().loginWasCancelled(pane);
                }
            });
            dialog.setVisible(true);

            return pane.wasAuthenticated();

        }

        public boolean wasAuthenticated() {
            return wasAuthenticated;
        }

        public void validateCreientials() {

            CredentialsView view = getCredentialsView();
            String userName = view.getUserName();
            char[] password = view.getPassword();
            if ((userName != null && userName.trim().length() > 0) && (password != null && password.length > 0)) {

                btnAuthenticate.setEnabled(true);

            } else {

                btnAuthenticate.setEnabled(false);

            }

        }

        @Override
        public void dismissView() {
            SwingUtilities.windowForComponent(this).dispose();
        }

        @Override
        public CredentialsView getCredentialsView() {
            return credientialsView;
        }

        @Override
        public void willAuthenticate() {
            getCredentialsView().willAuthenticate();
            btnAuthenticate.setEnabled(false);
        }

        @Override
        public void authenticationFailed() {
            getCredentialsView().authenticationFailed();
            validateCreientials();
            wasAuthenticated = false;
        }

        @Override
        public void authenticationSucceeded() {
            getCredentialsView().authenticationSucceeded();
            validateCreientials();
            wasAuthenticated = true;
        }

        public LoginViewController getLoginViewController() {
            return controller;
        }

        public void setLoginViewController(LoginViewController controller) {
            this.controller = controller;
        }

        @Override
        public void credientialsDidChange(CredentialsView view) {
            validateCreientials();
        }

    }

    public static class CredentialsPane extends JPanel implements CredentialsView {

        private CredentialsViewController controller;

        private JTextField userNameField;
        private JPasswordField passwordField;

        public CredentialsPane(CredentialsViewController controller) {
            setCredentialsViewController(controller);
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            userNameField = new JTextField(20);
            passwordField = new JPasswordField(20);

            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.gridx = 0;
            gbc.gridy = 0;
            gbc.insets = new Insets(2, 2, 2, 2);
            gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.EAST;
            add(new JLabel("Username: "), gbc);

            gbc.gridy++;
            add(new JLabel("Password: "), gbc);

            gbc.gridx = 1;
            gbc.gridy = 0;
            gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
            gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
            add(userNameField, gbc);
            gbc.gridy++;
            add(passwordField, gbc);

            DocumentListener listener = new DocumentListener() {
                @Override
                public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
                    getCredentialsViewController().credientialsDidChange(CredentialsPane.this);
                }

                @Override
                public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
                    getCredentialsViewController().credientialsDidChange(CredentialsPane.this);
                }

                @Override
                public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
                    getCredentialsViewController().credientialsDidChange(CredentialsPane.this);
                }
            };

            userNameField.getDocument().addDocumentListener(listener);
            passwordField.getDocument().addDocumentListener(listener);

        }

        @Override
        public CredentialsViewController getCredentialsViewController() {
            return controller;
        }

        @Override
        public String getUserName() {
            return userNameField.getText();
        }

        @Override
        public char[] getPassword() {
            return passwordField.getPassword();
        }

        @Override
        public void willAuthenticate() {
            userNameField.setEnabled(false);
            passwordField.setEnabled(false);
        }

        @Override
        public void authenticationFailed() {
            userNameField.setEnabled(true);
            passwordField.setEnabled(true);

            userNameField.requestFocusInWindow();
            userNameField.selectAll();

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Authentication has failed", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }

        @Override
        public void authenticationSucceeded() {
            // Really don't care, but you might want to stop animation, for example...
        }

        public void setCredentialsViewController(CredentialsViewController controller) {
            this.controller = controller;
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: I'm very thankful for your explicit answer, but I only got half of what you said as your mentioned interface only seems to mean shifting my problem with the ActionListener to the interface, doesn't it? Where to implement the interface? Who should be able to use it? I'm sorry if I seem dumb here, but your `MainViewListener` interface, esp. the function does not seem clear to me as I don't understand how that's gonna behave with the closing action.

Comment: From my perspective, you would attach an `ActionListener` to the button within the view.  The problem then, is how to communicate that to the controller, as the controller shouldn't care how the "close" action is triggered, only that it is, so I would use some kind of communication interface which described the possible actions that the view might create and the which the controller is expected to respond to.  It then saves you from having to have `ActionListener`s, `ChangeListener`s, `PropertyChangeListener`s strung between them.  You just the view to say, hay controller I did "this"...

Comment: This a multi layered concept.  The view would implement an interface (describing the contract of the view to the controller) that would allow the controller to manage it.  The controller would register an interface (listener) to the view allowing it to be notified when certain events occur within the view.  The view would manage it's own internal event managed (the `ActionListener` for example) and via the controller/view listener interface, tell the controller that something happened, this decouples the controller and view from each other, which is kind of the point...

Comment: Ah ok. So plainly said, the view contains actionListeners and implements interface so the controller can use the interface functions, gotcha until here. But how would this "register an interface (listener) to the view" thing work in Java? I've never done something like this yet, so I'd be glad if you could provide me some example for that. Thanks.

Comment: You've passed references of objects via methods to other classes?

Comment: Sure, I did. Probably I'm painting a wrong picture in my mind, but I can only get it straight this far that I create a listener (what listener might that be anyway?) controller side which is called by what? I thought the view shouldn't know about the controller... Or I'm getting it totally wrong and the view is actually invoking an interface method which then would mean the view is active and the controller passive? Sorry, it still confuses me. :-/

Comment: I'm honestly thinking that a code snippet might help way more to understand it than reading all the theory in here as there's probably simply a lack of knowledge to me about what is done with which Java command(s).

Comment: Be careful for what you wish for, I've updated the answer with a working example of what I'm talking about.  The MVC adds a lot more work, but it makes for a much more flexible design, like good OO, you need to plan ahead...

Comment: Thank you very much! :) I had to sleep on it for a night. Honestly, this is still very confusing to me as I've never done it this way before so it's totally new to me. But thanks for taking your time to actually provide something I can learn with and sooner or later I'll fully understand it. Kind regards, jaySon

Comment: Just remember, Swing is not a pure MVC, this is going to leave a lot of grey areas

Comment: I'd be curious as to why this would attract a download vote

Comment: "but the view and model should never interact, " Is this not an MVP pattern, instead of MVC?

Comment: @the_symathizer It depends, if you read the Apple documentation of MVC, the the model and view should never talk directly with each other

Answer (score 4):

They are associated with the control, but they don't have to be a direct part of the control. For instance, please see the code posted below that I was preparing for another question, one on anonymous inner classes and coupling, here I give all my buttons anonymous inner Actions (which are ActionListeners, of course), and then use the Actions to change the GUI state. Any listeners to the GUI (the control) will be notified of this change, and can then act accordingly.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*; 
import java.beans.PropertyChangeEvent;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeListener;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.SwingPropertyChangeSupport;

public class AnonymousInnerEg2 {
   private static void createAndShowUI() {
      GuiModel2 model = new GuiModel2();
      GuiPanel2 guiPanel = new GuiPanel2();
      GuiControl2 guiControl = new GuiControl2();
      guiControl.setGuiPanel(guiPanel);
      guiControl.setGuiModel(model);
      try {
         guiControl.init();
      } catch (GuiException2 e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
         System.exit(-1);
      }

      JFrame frame = new JFrame("AnonymousInnerEg");
      frame.getContentPane().add(guiPanel);
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.pack();
      frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            createAndShowUI();
         }
      });
   }
}

enum GuiState {
   BASE("Base"), START("Start"), END("End");
   private String name;

   private GuiState(String name) {
      this.name = name;
   }

   public String getName() {
      return name;
   }

}

class GuiModel2 {
   public static final String STATE = "state";
   private SwingPropertyChangeSupport support = new SwingPropertyChangeSupport(this);
   private GuiState state = GuiState.BASE;

   public GuiState getState() {
      return state;
   }

   public void setState(GuiState state) {
      GuiState oldValue = this.state;
      GuiState newValue = state;
      this.state = state;
      support.firePropertyChange(STATE, oldValue, newValue);
   }
   
   public void addPropertyChangeListener(PropertyChangeListener l) {
      support.addPropertyChangeListener(l);
   }

   public void removePropertyChangeListener(PropertyChangeListener l) {
      support.removePropertyChangeListener(l);
   }
}

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
class GuiPanel2 extends JPanel {
   public static final String STATE = "state";
   private String state = GuiState.BASE.getName();
   private JLabel stateField = new JLabel("", SwingConstants.CENTER);

   public GuiPanel2() {

      JPanel btnPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, 0, 5, 0));
      for (final GuiState guiState : GuiState.values()) {
         btnPanel.add(new JButton(new AbstractAction(guiState.getName()) {
            {
               int mnemonic = (int) getValue(NAME).toString().charAt(0);
               putValue(MNEMONIC_KEY, mnemonic);
            }

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
               String name = getValue(NAME).toString();
               setState(name);
            }
         }));
      }
      
      setLayout(new BorderLayout());
      add(stateField, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
      add(btnPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
   }

   public String getState() {
      return state;
   }

   public void setState(String state) {
      String oldValue = this.state;
      String newValue = state;
      this.state = state;
      firePropertyChange(STATE, oldValue, newValue);
   }
   
   public void setStateField(String name) {
      stateField.setText(name);
   }

}

class GuiControl2 {
   private GuiPanel2 guiPanel;
   private GuiModel2 model;
   private boolean allOK = false;

   public void setGuiPanel(GuiPanel2 guiPanel) {
      this.guiPanel = guiPanel;
      guiPanel.addPropertyChangeListener(GuiPanel2.STATE,
            new GuiPanelStateListener());
   }
   
   public void init() throws GuiException2 {
      if (model == null) {
         throw new GuiException2("Model is null");
      }
      if (guiPanel == null) {
         throw new GuiException2("GuiPanel is null");
      }
      allOK = true;
      guiPanel.setStateField(model.getState().getName());
   }

   public void setGuiModel(GuiModel2 model) {
      this.model = model;
      model.addPropertyChangeListener(new ModelListener());
   }

   private class GuiPanelStateListener implements PropertyChangeListener {
      @Override
      public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
         if (!allOK) {
            return;
         }
         if (GuiPanel2.STATE.equals(evt.getPropertyName())) {
            String text = guiPanel.getState();
            model.setState(GuiState.valueOf(text.toUpperCase()));
         }
      }
   }
   
   private class ModelListener implements PropertyChangeListener {
      @Override
      public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
         if (!allOK) {
            return;
         }
         if (GuiModel2.STATE.equals(evt.getPropertyName())) {
            GuiState state = (GuiState) evt.getNewValue();
            guiPanel.setStateField(state.getName());
         }
      }
   }
}

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
class GuiException2 extends Exception {

   public GuiException2() {
      super();
   }

   public GuiException2(String message) {
      super(message);
   }
}
```

Note in warning though: I am not a professional coder or even a university trained coder, so please take this as just my opinion only.

Comment: FYI: The Swing implementation of the MVC is more like (VC)M, where the controller and view are the same class.  A assume this was done  mostly because of the look and feel...personally, I prefer it, as you get a self contained unit of work, but it can argued that it reduces the flexibility and extendability of the component...but whatever... +1

Comment: @MadProgrammer: thanks for your astute comments and your great answer. I always learn much from your posts. My main questions are how to handle MVC in a large complex program, mainly how to hook up the listeners, how to scale things up. I have not resolved this issue yet.

Comment: This seems to be a common issue.  I think `Action`s is a start, but they tend to be focused on the view side.  One way might be to describe what the view is intended to do and design an `interface` around it.  There's no reason why a view can't contain other MVCs and one model could feed information to another model which could affect it's associated controller and so on and so forth. The core issue, again, is Swing isn't a pure MVC, so it's like trying to squeeze an elephant into a mini's boot, sure, it might be possible, but it ain't going to be pretty

Comment: @MadProgrammer: Yeah, I agree. MVC does not have to be all or none, and there can be finer granularity to it, with mini-MVC's all adding to the greater whole. Thanks for your insights!

Comment: The example I did for the OP has one of the views acting as the controller for it's child view, it makes sense in this case, but might not always be the case...

Comment: Hmm... the problem I have with this sort of design is that it leaks implementation details ("I have used MVC to implement my component") into the public API ("you must create a controller and pass it to the view when you construct it.") Thus when I do this sort of thing, I like to create the controller from the view. The controller interface, controller implementation and view interface can all be package local and nobody has to know they're there.

Answer (score 1):

## Introduction

The model / view / controller (MVC) pattern can be applied to Swing in the following way.

1. The view reads information from the model.
2. The view may not update the model.
3. The controller will update the model and repaint / revalidate the view.

Now, in Swing, there's usually no master controller to "rule them all".  Each `ActionListener` and `AbstractAction` is its own controller, responsible for the actions of that particular `JButton` or keyboard key binding.

Here's an example of a Swing GUI coded with MVC in mind.

[image: Ripples]

This GUI draws ever-widening circles where you left-click on the drawing `JPanel`.  Like ripples in a pond.  The GUI is simple enough to explain in a Stack Overflow answer but complex enough to serve as a good MVC illustration.

## Explanation

The MVC pattern is called the MVC pattern because you create the model first, then the view, and finally the controllers.  Now, this can be an iterative process.  Often, I find I need something in the model when I'm constructing the view.

Starting with the view, or worse, the controllers, usually leads to a mess that can't be tested or debugged.  Sure, sometimes you need the view to verify the model.  But I'm not so good a developer that I can write dozens of lines of working code.

I write a little, test a lot, and usually find that I've caused problems for myself.  Since I write a little, I only have a little bit of code to debug at a time.

### Model

The model consists of two classes, the `RipplesModel` class and the `Circle` class.  The `Circle` class is a plain Java getter / setter class that holds the center `java.awt.Point`, the `int` radius, and a `java.awt.Color` for the outline color.  Yes, I'm using `java.awt` classes in the model.  These awt classes are meant to hold information for drawing.

The `RipplesModel` class is a plain Java getter / setter class that holds a `java.util.List` of `Circle` instances.  This `List` will be used by the drawing `JPanel` to draw the `Circle` instances.

Generally, your Swing model will consist of one or more plain Java getter / setter classes.

### View

The view consists of a `JFrame` and a drawing `JPanel`.  The `JFrame` code contains a `WindowListener` so that I can stop the animation `Thread`.  The `WindowListener` is one of the controller classes.  It's pretty simple, so I made it an anonymous class.

The controller code can reside inside one of the view classes.  The MVC model doesn't dictate where the code resides.  The MVC model dictates where the code is executed.

The drawing `JPanel` draws the `Circle` instances on the drawing `JPanel`.  Period.  The controllers are responsible for changing the radius of the `Circle` instances and running the animation.

I use a `JFrame`.  I extend a `JPanel` because I override the `paintComponent` method.  The only time you should extend a Swing component is when you want to override one or more of the class methods.

### Controller

There are three controller classes in this GUI.  I've already mentioned the anonymous `WindowListener` class that stops the animation `Thread`.

The `RipplesListener` class is a `MouseListener` that listens for a mouse press.  The listener creates a `Circle` instance where you left-click.

The `Animation` `Runnable` increments the radius of each `Circle` instance, and calls for a repaint of the drawing `JPanel`.  The `JFrame` class contains a `repaint` method, which in turn calls the drawing `JPanel` `repaint` method.

The controller classes don't have to know how the view works.  They just have to know that the `JFrame` (main view) class has a `repaint` method.  This helps to enforce a separation of concerns, which is one of the main reasons you use the MVC pattern.

The `Animation` `Runnable` runs in a separate `Thread`, so that the GUI Thread, the [Event Dispatch Thread](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html), is not blocked.  Today, I'd probably use a Swing `Timer`, but when I wrote this, I was used to writing my own animation `Runnable`.

## Code

Here's the complete runnable code.  I made all the classes inner classes so I could post this code as one block.

```
import java.awt.BasicStroke;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class Ripples implements Runnable {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Ripples());
    }

    private Animation animation;

    private DrawingPanel drawingPanel;

    private RipplesModel model;

    public Ripples() {
        model = new RipplesModel();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Ripples");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent event) {
                stopAnimation();
                frame.dispose();
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });

        drawingPanel = new DrawingPanel(model);
        frame.add(drawingPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        animation = new Animation(this, model);
        new Thread(animation).start();
    }

    public void repaint() {
        drawingPanel.repaint();
    }

    private void stopAnimation() {
        if (animation != null) {
            animation.setRunning(false);
        }
    }

    public class DrawingPanel extends JPanel {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        private RipplesModel model;

        public DrawingPanel(RipplesModel model) {
            this.model = model;
            setBackground(Color.BLACK);
            setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 500));
            addMouseListener(new RipplesListener(model));
        }

        @Override
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);

            Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
            g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
                    RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
            g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(5f));

            List<Circle> circles = model.getCircles();
            for (Circle circle : circles) {
                Point p = circle.getCenter();
                int radius = circle.getRadius();
                g2.setColor(circle.getColor());
                g2.drawOval(p.x - radius, p.y - radius,
                        2 * radius, 2 * radius);
            }
        }

    }

    public class RipplesListener extends MouseAdapter {

        private Random random;

        private RipplesModel model;

        public RipplesListener(RipplesModel model) {
            this.model = model;
            this.random = new Random();
        }

        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent event) {
            model.addCircle(new Circle(event.getPoint(),
                    createColor()));
        }

        private Color createColor() {
            int r = random.nextInt(128) + 128;
            int g = random.nextInt(128) + 128;
            int b = random.nextInt(128) + 128;
            return new Color(r, g, b);
        }
    }

    public class Animation implements Runnable {

        private volatile boolean running;

        private Ripples frame;

        private RipplesModel model;

        public Animation(Ripples frame, RipplesModel model) {
            this.frame = frame;
            this.model = model;
            this.running = true;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (running) {
                sleep(20L);
                incrementRadius();
                repaint();
            }
        }

        private void incrementRadius() {
            List<Circle> circles = model.getCircles();
            for (Circle circle : circles) {
                circle.incrementRadius();
            }
        }

        private void sleep(long delay) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(delay);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        private void repaint() {
            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    frame.repaint();
                }
            });
        }

        public synchronized void setRunning(boolean running) {
            this.running = running;
        }

    }

    public class RipplesModel {

        private List<Circle> circles;

        public RipplesModel() {
            this.circles = new ArrayList<>();
        }

        public void addCircle(Circle circle) {
            this.circles.add(circle);
        }

        public List<Circle> getCircles() {
            return circles;
        }

    }

    public class Circle {

        private int radius;

        private final Color color;

        private final Point center;

        public Circle(Point center, Color color) {
            this.center = center;
            this.color = color;
            this.radius = 10;
        }

        public void incrementRadius() {
            radius = (++radius > 200) ? 10 : radius;
        }

        public Color getColor() {
            return color;
        }

        public int getRadius() {
            return radius;
        }

        public Point getCenter() {
            return center;
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

A am currently learning Java in school. The teachers told us, that the listeners always have to be declared inside the *Controller* class. The way I do it, is to implement a method e.g. *listeners()*. Inside are all listener-declarations using anonymous classes. That's the way my teachers want it to see, but frankly, i'm not really sure if they got it all correct.