# Changing the value of a textfied in JFrame class1, JFrame class2,... by selecting an item from jtable in Jframe class3

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jtextfield

I have 14 `JFrame` classes and one `JFrame` class holding a `JTable` which acts as a calendar. I want the date of a text field or any other component in any of the 14 `JFrame` classes to be changed when the user selects the date from the `JTable` calendar . Now, the frames appear one at a time and the jtable is instantiated from a `JButton` on any of the 14 JFrame classes.

My dilemma is how to identify the `JFrame` class that has instantiated the `JFrame` that contains the `JTable` so that it's text field value can be changed.

Code that instantiates the JFrame containing the table:

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    JFrame frmMain = new Calender();
    frmMain.setVisible(true);
    frmMain.setSize(367, 342);
}
```

Code that changes the value of the textfield from one of the 14 `JFrame` classes :

```
@Override
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent me) {
    if (me.getClickCount()==2){
        int selected1 =    jTable1.getSelectionModel().getLeadSelectionIndex();
        int selected2 =jTable1.getColumnModel().getSelectionModel().getLeadSelectionIndex();

        Object c = jTable1.getModel().getValueAt(selected1, selected2);
        SowInformation.jTextField4.setText(c.toString());
        this.setVisible(false);
    }
}
```

Where `SowInformation` is one of the 14 `JFrame` classes.

Comment: *"SowInformation is one of the 14 JFrame classes"*  That's 13 too many.  See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9554636/418556)

Comment: Thanks Andrew, using Multiple JFrames is a good practice but am in the final stages of my application and this would change the whole architecture. Any solution to my problem??

Comment: *"Any solution to my problem??"*  Fix the architecture.  Trying to make multiple frames work is like trying to patch the cracks in the architecture with putty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @AndrewThompson wisely mentioned, [the use of multiple JFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9554657/1795530) is a bad practice. In this case a (non-)modal dialog would be a better choice.

Now let's assume you choose non-modal dialogs, then you still having the same problem. There are several ways to solve it but essentially you need to keep a reference to the frame/dialog which opened the calendar's frame. Even better, you can use interfaces to define a contract to update a text field isolating the desired behavior from the actual implementation. For example:

```
public interface IUpdateText {

    public void updateText(String text);

}
```

Now your calendar's frame needs to keep a reference to a `IUpdateText` compliant object:

```
class Calender extends JFrame {
    ...
    private IUpdateText updateText;
    ...
    public void setIUpdateText(IUpdateText ut) {
        this.updateText = ut;
    }
    ...
}
```

Then in your mouse listener implementation just call `updateText()` method:

```
@Override
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent me) {
    if (me.getClickCount()==2){
        int selectedRow = jTable1.getSelectedRow();
        int selectedColumn = jTable1.getSelectedColumn();
        if (selectedRow > -1 && selectedColumn > -1) {
            Object value = jTable1.getValueAt(selectedRow, selectedColumn); // ask the value to the view, not the model. Otherwise you need to convert both row and column indexes
            this.updateText.updateText(value.toString());
            this.setVisible(false); // maybe this.dispose() instead ?
        }
    }
}
```

Of course all your other frames/dialogs that can open this calendar frame would have to implement `IUpdateText` interface. For example `SowInformation` frame:

```
class SowInformation extends JFrame implements IUpdateText {
    ...
    private JTextField jTextField4;
    ...
    @Override
    public void updateText(String text) {
        this.jTextfield4.setText(text);
    }
    ...
}
```

And finally set the `IUpdateText` compliant object to the calendar frame when you instantiate it:

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    Calender frmMain = new Calender();
    calender.setIUpdateText(this);  // assuming 'this' is an IUpdateText interface compliant
    frmMain.pack();
    frmMain.setVisible(true);
}
```

---

#### Other comments

From an architectural point of view this problem might be better solved through an MVC pattern, having a Controller which acts as an intermediary for both frames/dialogs. There are multiple questions [about MVC pattern and Swing](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=swing+mvc) here in SO but I really like the example/explanation shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26518274/1795530) by @MadProgrammer (a real Swing guru).

Comment: I thought about that too but I think OP wants to listen for a mouse double-click to trigger the action. However you made me realize that implementation has several issues (asking the *model* for data using *view* indexes is one of them). I'm editing now. Thanks! @mKorbel

Answer (score 0):

another thing you can do is use a static variable and set it's value just before you instantiate the JFrame and according to it's value you can decide which class has instantiated JFrame.

Comment: @Dic19. Thank you so much for being smart. Your solution worked perfectly. And to you all for your pertinent solutions.

Comment: @AugustineBazirake why don't you accept my answer. thank you!

Comment: I didn't reject your answer only that i didn't understand how to implement it. Although i have been reading java for a while, but am working on my very first project, so i may not easily translate the not so direct answers into code. But thanks so much, you could elaborate with code.

Comment: @Googo it's not clear which approach helped you to solve the problem but in any case you should mark the answer that helped as accepted in order to guide future visitors.

Comment: @dic 19, Sorry for this, you know am a newbi to this platform but am really appreciative of the support that i have received. Thanks alot