# Component management in Java Swing

Tags: java, swing, model-view-controller

I am working with Swing for some time now and I am constantly thinking about if my management of components is really useful and a good way to do so. Let me explain:

```
public class Main extends JFrame{

  private MyPanel panel = new MyPanel();

  public Main(){
    // do something
  }

  public JButton getButton(){
    return this.panel.getButton();
  }
}

public class MyPanel extends JPanel{

  private JButton button = new JButton();

  public MyPanel(){
    // do something
  }

  public JButton getButton(){
    return this.button;
  }
}

public class Controller{

  public Controller(JFrame frame){
    frame.getButton().addSomeListener(new ExampleListener(frame));
  }
}

public class ExampleListener implements SomeListener{

  private JButton button;

  public ExampleListener(JFrame frame){
    this.button = frame.getButton();
  }

  @Override
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
    // do something
  }
}
```

My question is about the way I work with event listeners. I used to save a reference to each component that needs some listener in the top of my hierarchy (in this case the frame) and give the frame as parameter to a central logic class. The central logic class gives always a reference to the topmost hierarchy component to the listener and these "extract" needed components with help of getter methods. As you can see, I use a nested "getButton()" method inside the frame. I really would like to know if there are some drawbacks or similar with this management. If there is, can you recommend some good ways to organize components?

PS: I know that Swing works good with the MVC pattern, but I don't really know if I managed to do so.

PPS: I know that it is considered bad practice to extend JComponents without overriding desired features. This here is only for demonstration purposes.

Sorry if  similar question already exists. :)

Comment: Neither the controller or model should really hold a direct reference to any UI components.  The UI, controller and model should communicate with each other via the use of interfaces, which describe the contractual requirements between each layer.  This way, it's easy to replace any element without adversely affecting the other elements

Comment: An example would be really appreciated since I'm clueless. I did never learn any different than this. :/

Comment: For [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26517856/java-swing-where-do-actionlisteners-belong-according-to-mvc-pattern/26518274#26518274)

Comment: Thank you very much. I read about your answer and about MVC in more detail and now I am proud that I know how to use it. Thanks again. :)

Comment: [Model-View-Controller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) and [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26517856/java-swing-where-do-actionlisteners-belong-according-to-mvc-pattern/26518274#26518274) might help