# How MVC work with java swing GUI

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, model-view-controller

Lets say I have a swing GUI which has textfeild and button. When I click button I want to save that value in text in db and return joptionpane "success" message. 

The way I used to do this is 

***Model*** : JDBC class

***View*** : GUI : In that button's '*action performed*' action I call save method with parameter.

```
   Controller con = new Controller();
   con.save(text1.getText());
```

***Controller*** : Write a save method.

```
   JDBC db = new                             
   public void save(jTextfeild text){     
   text= text1.getText();
   boolean b= db.putData("insert into .. values(text)");
   if(b){
   JOptionPane("Success"); 
   }
 }
```

This is how I started. But later I understood this is not how this should be and this is utterly unsafe and stupid. 

I really want to learn how to do this in MVC properly. Please be kind enough to explain this to with a small example. Thank you for your time.

Comment: `"But later I understood this is not how this should be and this is utterly unsafe and stupid...."` -- please elaborate: What specifically is utterly unsafe and stupid?

Comment: sql injections and this is not real way to use mvc

Comment: Take a look at my [Retro Snake Game](http://java-articles.info/articles/?p=768) article to see how to use the MVC pattern with a reasonably complex Swing application.

Comment: Thank you @GilbertLeBlanc.. I will look in to it..

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is a difficult subject to grasp in something like Swing, which already uses a form of MVC, albeit more like VC-M, where the model is separated from the view and controller, but where the view and controller are combined.

Think about a `JButton`, you don't supply a controller to manage how it's triggered when a user presses a key or clicks on it with the mouse, this is done internally and you are notified about the actions when the occur.

With this in mind, you need to allow the view to be semi self managed.  For instance, based on your requirements, the view would have a button and text field.

The view itself would manage the interactions between the user and the button itself (maintain a internal `ActionListener` for example), but would then provide notifications to the controller about any state changes that the controller might be interested in.

In a more pure sense of a MVC, the view and model won't know anything about each other and the controller would manage them.  This is a little contradictive to how Swing works, as Swing allows you to pass the model directly to the view, see just about any Swing component.

This doesn't mean that you can't make things work, but you need to know where the concept can falter or needs to be "massaged" to work better.

Normally, when I approach these type of things, I take step back and look at much wider picture, for example.

- You have a view which can accept text and produce text or changes to it
- You have a model which can load and modify text, but provides little other events
- You have a controller which wants to get text from the model and supply it to the view and monitor for changes to the text by the view and update them within the model

Now, MVC works REALLY well with the concept of "code to interfaces (not implementation)", to that extent, I tend to start with the contracts...

## View contract...

```
public interface TextView {

    public void setText(String text);
    public String getText();
    public void addTextViewObserver(TextViewObserver observer);
    public void removeTextViewObserver(TextViewObserver observer);

}

public interface TextViewObserver {
    public void textWasChanged(TextView view);
}
```

Now, one of the requirements of the view is to generate events when the text has changed in some meaningful way, to this end, I've used a simple observer pattern to implement.  Now you could argue that the controller is the observer, but to my mind, the controller may have functionality that I don't want to expose to the view (like the model for instance)

## Model contract...

Next comes the model...

```
public interface TextModel {
    public String getText();
    public void setText(String text);
}
```

pretty simple really.  Now, you might consider adding some kind of `Exception` to these methods to allow the model the ability to fail for some reason, but the `Exception` should be as generic as you can make it (or even a custom `Exception`), so that you can replace the implementation should you need to

## Controller contract...

And finally, the controller...

```
public interface TextViewController {

    public TextView getTextView();
    public TextModel getTextModel();

}
```

again, pretty simple.  You might have a more complex requirement for your controller, but for this example, this is about all we really need.

## Implementations...

### View...

```
public class TextViewPane extends JPanel implements TextView {

    private JTextField textField;
    private JButton updateButton;
    private List<TextViewObserver> observers;

    public TextViewPane() {
        observers = new ArrayList<>(25);
        textField = new JTextField(25);
        updateButton = new JButton("Update");
        updateButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                fireTextWasChanged();
            }
        });

        setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
        add(textField, gbc);
        add(updateButton, gbc);
    }

    @Override
    public void setText(String text) {
        textField.setText(text);
    }

    @Override
    public String getText() {
        return textField.getText();
    }

    @Override
    public void addTextViewObserver(TextViewObserver observer) {
        observers.add(observer);
    }

    @Override
    public void removeTextViewObserver(TextViewObserver observer) {
        observers.remove(observer);
    }

    protected void fireTextWasChanged() {
        for (TextViewObserver observer : observers) {
            observer.textWasChanged(this);
        }
    }

}
```

### Model...

```
public class SimpleTextModel implements TextModel {

    private String text = "This is some text";

    @Override
    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }

    @Override
    public void setText(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

}
```

### Controller...

```
public class SimpleTextController implements TextViewController, TextViewObserver {

    private TextView view;
    private TextModel model;

    public SimpleTextController(TextView view, TextModel model) {
        this.view = Objects.requireNonNull(view, "TextView can not null");
        this.model = Objects.requireNonNull(model, "TextModel can not be null");
        view.addTextViewObserver(this);
    }

    @Override
    public TextView getTextView() {
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public TextModel getTextModel() {
        return model;
    }

    @Override
    public void textWasChanged(TextView view) {
        getTextModel().setText(view.getText());
    }
}
```

## Putting it together...

```
TextViewPane view = new TextViewPane();
TextModel model = new SimpleTextModel();
TextViewController controller = new SimpleTextController(view, model);

JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
frame.add(view);
frame.pack();
frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
frame.setVisible(true);
```

Now, all this is just an example of one possible solution.  You could have a controller implementation which has a particular implementation of the model or view or both, for example.

The point is, you just shouldn't care.  The controller doesn't care how the view is implemented, it only cares that it will generate `textWasChanged` events.  The model doesn't care about the view at all (and visa-versa) and the controller doesn't care about model, only that it will get and set some text.

For a more complex example, you can have a look at [Java and GUI - Where do ActionListeners belong according to MVC pattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26517856/java-swing-where-do-actionlisteners-belong-according-to-mvc-pattern/26518274#26518274)

## After thoughts

- This is just ONE possible way to approach the problem.  For example, you could limit the view to a single observer.
- You should always be thinking "can I change any one part of the MVC and will it still work?"  This makes you think about the possible issues that changing any one part of the implementation might have on the surrounding contracts.  You should get to the point that it simply doesn't matter how each layer is implemented
- A view may act as a controller for another sub-view (or act as a container for another controller of a sub-view).  This can scare people sometimes, but it's possible for a view to act as parent container for one or more sub controllers/views, this allows you to develop complex UIs
- Don't expose implementation details in your contracts, for example, the model shouldn't throw a `SQLException`, as another implementation might not be based on a SQL based solution.  Don't expose UI elements, this means that ALL implementations would then need to implement those elements.  What happens if I want a implementation of the view that presents a `JComboBox` to the user instead of `JTextField`?  This is also the reason I don't use a `ActionListener` in the view contract, because I have no idea how a `textWasChanged` event might actually be generated by an implementation of the view

Comment: Note that in Swing, both the model and the view part have events, where your example only has them in the view part. I think you need changes on the model side as well. How else can you share your model across multiple views, and have all the views update themself when the model is changed through one specific view

Comment: @Robin My example is simple and I didn't see the need for the model to generate an event, in this example.that doesn't mean that it can't, it's just I didn't see the need to add one for this example. I believe in the linked example I did

Comment: @Robin You could equally argue that it's the responsibility of the controller to generate these events, as a parent controller I might not be able to (or want to) listen directly to the model, but this is a design choice ;)