# Separating logic from Jframe file in Netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, jframe, logic

I'm trying to separate the logic from Jframe in a different class under the same package. But when I add functions for Jframe conponents such as a button it's added in the Jframe file. And I can't access my objects in my logic file from there. What's the correct way to separate logic and graphic?

Comment: Start by taking a look at [Model-View-Controller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller), but basically you're on the right track.  Instead of providing direct access to the components consider provide getters (and setters) which provide access to their state.  You could use a interface as a contract between the controller and the view to describe what the controller can get/do to the view as well as provide some event notification so the view can notify the controller when something important happens

Comment: Swing itself is a type of MVC, trying to force a pure MVC onto is just asking for headaches, instead, you should focus on wrapping an MVC around it's existing framework

Comment: For [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31576623/how-mvc-work-with-java-swing-gui/31576899#31576899), [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26517856/java-and-gui-where-do-actionlisteners-belong-according-to-mvc-pattern/26518274#26518274), [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31602113/listener-placement-adhering-to-the-traditional-non-mediator-mvc-pattern/31604919#31604919)

Comment: @MadProgrammer Could you be more specific? Let's give it a context. Say I have only one object Data containing an int, a Jframe contains a button which I want it to add 1 to Data. How should I set up the system?

Comment: Well, that describes a model, when the button is clicked it needs to call the models `add` method, which performs the physical actions.  This way, when you want to change the logic you can just change the model, the rest will continue to work

Comment: @MadProgrammer I went to read some introduction about MVC. The model part seems easy to understand. But I'm still a bit confused how the View and Controller part seperate from each other. Can you explain a bit still based on the example above? Also, I saw MVC are 3 objects so the main method is in none of the 3, am I correct?

Comment: With regards to examples, I've linked three, I believe the majority of which have a working example. Normally, yes, you would also have a controller which acts as a bridge between your model and your view. The problem you will have is, Swing itself is a form of MVC (albit in the form of VC-M), which makes it harder to wrap a pure MVC around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Could you be more specific? Let's give it a context. Say I have only one object Data containing an int, a Jframe contains a button which I want it to add 1 to Data. How should I set up the system?

This basically describes a model, the model is responsible for controlling the logic and providing the required functionality for other interested parties to work with it

So you might start with a simple contract...

```
public interface DataModel {
    public void add();
    public int getData();
}
```

You I would then create an `abstract` version of the model which does most of the boiler plate work...

```
public abstract class AbstractDataModel implements DataModel {

    private int data;

    public AbstractDataModel(int value) {
        this.data = value;
    }

    public void add(int delta) {
        data += delta;
    }

    @Override
    public int getData() {
        return data;
    }
}
```

Which then allows me to create simple concrete implementations...

```
public class AddByOneDataModel extends AbstractDataModel {

    public AddByOneDataModel(int value) {
        super(value);
    }

    @Override
    public void add() {
        add(1);
    }
}
```

or if you wanted to be really lazy, you could just do...

```
public class DeltaDataModel extends AbstractDataModel {

    private int delta;

    public DeltaDataModel(int delta, int value) {
        super(value);
        this.delta = delta;
    }

    @Override
    public void add() {
        add(delta);
    }

}
```

but, so far, the UI's not be involved in any of it, it doesn't care, it will only want an instance of `DataModel`

Then your UI might look something like...

```
public class TestPane extends JPanel {

    private DataModel model;
    private JButton add;

    public TestPane() {
        //...
        add = new JButton("Add");
        add.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                getModel().add();
                int data = getModel().getData();
                // Update the UI in some meaningful way...
            }
        });
        //...
    }

    public void setModel(DataModel model) {
        this.model = model;
    }

    public DataModel getModel() {
        return model;
    }

}
```

This would then allow you to do things like...

```
TestPane pane = new TestPane();
pane.setModel(new DeltaDataModel(0, 100));
```

which allows you to specify the actual functionality of the model you want to use (because who knows what you'll want to do in the future)

> But I'm still a bit confused how the View and Controller part seperate from each other. Can you explain a bit still based on the example above? Also, I saw MVC are 3 objects so the main method is in none of the 3, am I correct?

As explained in [How MVC work with java swing GUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31576623/how-mvc-work-with-java-swing-gui/31576899#31576899), [Java and GUI - Where do ActionListeners belong according to MVC pattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26517856/java-and-gui-where-do-actionlisteners-belong-according-to-mvc-pattern/26518274#26518274), [Listener Placement Adhering to the Traditional (non-mediator) MVC Pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31602113/listener-placement-adhering-to-the-traditional-non-mediator-mvc-pattern/31604919#31604919) and verious other answers on the subject, Swing is an implementation of MVC, albit more like M-VC, where the components are self contained views and controllers and the model is dynamic

This makes it difficult to try and wrap a more traditional MVC around.  Instead, we work with the concept of a view been a series of components contained with a container which then conforms to some specified contract.

In a more traditional MVC, the model and the view don't interact with each, they don't know anything about each other and instead the controller maintains the relationship.

## Model...

Let's go back and update our model.  In order to facilitate the MVC, we need to provide an [Observer Pattern](http://www.oodesign.com/observer-pattern.html) to it, so it can trigger notifications when the model is updated (because the model could be updated indepdently of the controller or view)

```
public abstract class AbstractDataModel implements DataModel {

    private List<ChangeListener> changeListeners;
    private int data;

    public AbstractDataModel(int value) {
        this.data = value;
        changeListeners = new ArrayList<>(25);
    }

    @Override
    public void addChangeListener(ChangeListener listener) {
        changeListeners.add(listener);
    }

    @Override
    public void removeChangeListener(ChangeListener listener) {
        changeListeners.remove(listener);
    }

    protected void fireStateChanged() {
        if (!changeListeners.isEmpty()) {
            ChangeEvent evt = new ChangeEvent(this);
            for (ChangeListener listener : changeListeners) {
                listener.stateChanged(evt);
            }
        }
    }

    public void add(int delta) {
        data += delta;
        fireStateChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public int getData() {
        return data;
    }
}

public class DeltaDataModel extends AbstractDataModel {

    private int delta;

    public DeltaDataModel(int value, int delta) {
        super(value);
        this.delta = delta;
    }

    @Override
    public void add() {
        add(delta);
    }

}

public class AddByOneDataModel extends DeltaDataModel {

    public AddByOneDataModel(int value) {
        super(value, 1);
    }
}
```

## View...

Next, let's have a look at the view.  First we define the contract for the view, this ensures that the controller can only do what what the contract says it can.

```
public interface AddView {
    public static final String ADD_ACTION_COMMAND = "Action.add";
    public void setData(int data);
    public void addActionListener(ActionListener listener);
    public void removeActionListener(ActionListener listener);
}
```

*nb: I might also be tempted to add a `getComponent` method which returns the actual `JComponent` which the implementation actually uses, but that will come down to what you want to do and is demonstrated in some of the other links*

And a physical implementation...

```
public class AddViewPane extends JPanel implements AddView {

    private JButton btn;
    private JLabel label;

    public AddViewPane() {
        setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;

        btn = new JButton("Add");
        label = new JLabel("...");

        add(btn, gbc);
        add(label, gbc);

        btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                fireAddAction();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void setData(int data) {
        label.setText(NumberFormat.getNumberInstance().format(data));
    }

    @Override
    public void addActionListener(ActionListener listener) {
        listenerList.add(ActionListener.class, listener);
    }

    @Override
    public void removeActionListener(ActionListener listener) {
        listenerList.remove(ActionListener.class, listener);
    }

    protected void fireAddAction() {
        ActionListener[] listeners = listenerList.getListeners(ActionListener.class);
        if (listeners.length > 0) {
            ActionEvent evt = new ActionEvent(this, ActionEvent.ACTION_PERFORMED, ADD_ACTION_COMMAND);
            for (ActionListener listener : listeners) {
                listener.actionPerformed(evt);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

## Controller...

Again, starting at the lowest level and building the funcitonality up

```
public interface AddController {
    public DataModel getModel();
    public AddView getView();
}

public class AbstractAddController implements AddController {

    private AddView view;
    private DataModel model;

    public AbstractAddController(AddView view, DataModel model) {
        this.view = view;
        this.model = model;

        view.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                getModel().add();
            }
        });

        model.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
                getView().setData(getModel().getData());
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public DataModel getModel() {
        return model;
    }

    @Override
    public AddView getView() {
        return view;
    }

}

public class DefaultAddController extends AbstractAddController {

    public DefaultAddController(AddView view, DataModel model) {
        super(view, model);
    }

}
```

## Putting it together...

And finally, you might be able to use something like...

```
EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        DataModel model = new AddByOneDataModel(0);
        AddViewPane view = new AddViewPane();
        DefaultAddController controller = new DefaultAddController(view, model);

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        // This is where having a getComponent method in
        // view interface would be helpful      
        frame.add(view);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
});
```

to put it all together