# How to change view in MVC controller in Java Swing?

Tags: java, swing, model-view-controller

I am creating swing app where it is necessary to log in at the beginning. After loging in I want app to change the view from loginPanel(which extends JPanel) to SearchPanel(which also extends JPanel). How to switch view in the controller?

```
public class MainFrame extends JFrame{

public JPanel cards;
private LoginController controller;

public MainFrame() {

    cards = new JPanel(new CardLayout());

    LoginPanel loginPanel = new LoginPanel();
    cards.add(loginPanel, "login");

    SearchView searchPanel = new SearchView();  
    cards.add(searchPanel, "search");

    add(cards);

    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
    setVisible(true);
}
```

Comment: Basically, you need to provide some means by which the controller knows when the user has been successfully validated and can then move to the next view

Comment: As a [runnable example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26517856/java-and-gui-where-do-actionlisteners-belong-according-to-mvc-pattern/26518274#26518274)