# Java ActionPerformed() method doesn't execute

Tags: java, swing, model-view-controller, actionlistener

I am using MVC. In my View In my View I have made a new button named jbOk and and did jbOk.setActionCommand("OK"). In my Controller in the actionPerformed() I made an if statement: if(actionCommand.equals("OK")), then it must print something. This doesn't print. Outside of the if statement I have made another System.out.println() which also doesn't print.

What am I doing wrong?

My View:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.Border;


import main.java.models.MapModel;
import main.resources.ConnectionManager;

public class MapView extends JPanel {
    public Image image;
    private JLabel jlImage;
    private JLabel jlName;
    private static JButton jbOk;
    private ArrayList<String> comboBoxValues;
    private JComboBox routeComboBox = new JComboBox();
    //private JComboBox<ArrayList<>>;
    private ActionListener actionListener;

    public MapView(){
        super(new FlowLayout());
        setSize(900, 450);
        this.add(getRouteComboBox());
        jbOk = new JButton("OK");
        jbOk.setActionCommand("OK");
        jbOk.addActionListener(this.actionListener);
        add(jbOk);
       // comboBoxValues.toArray();
    } //constructor end

    public void setComboBoxValues(ArrayList<String> comboBoxValues) {
        this.comboBoxValues = comboBoxValues;
        for (String item: comboBoxValues) {
            routeComboBox.addItem( item );
        }
    }

    public void setImage(Image image){
        this.image = image;
    }


    public MapView getView(){
        jlImage = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(this.image));
        add(jlImage);
        return this;
    }

    public void addListenerOfActions(ActionListener listenForAction) {
        this.actionListener = listenForAction;
    }

    public JComboBox getRouteComboBox(){
        return routeComboBox;
    }

} //class end
```

My Controller:

```
import main.app.view.MapView;
import main.java.models.MapModel;

import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.*;

public class MapController {
    private MapView view;
    private MapModel model;

    public MapController(MapView view, MapModel model) {
        this.view = view;

        MapController.ListenerOfActions listener = new MapController.ListenerOfActions();
        view.addListenerOfActions(listener);
        this.model = model;
        this.model.getAllRoutes();

        ArrayList<String> routes = model.getAllRoutes();
        this.view.getRouteComboBox().getSelectedItem();
        this.view.setComboBoxValues(routes);
        System.out.println(routes);

        this.updateMap(2);
        this.view.setVisible(true);
    } //constructor end

    private void updateMap(int routeID){
        model.fillCoordinateListArray(routeID);
        Image image = null;
            try {
                URL url = new URL("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?" +
                        "&size=600x450" +
                        "&maptype=roadmap" +
                        this.model.parseCoordinates() +
                        //"San+Francisco,CA" + "%7C" +
                        //"&markers=label:1%7C40.702147,-74.015794" + "%7C" +

                        "&key=AIzaSyAbLM94WcbkB-cf_ubHXOHmCDSsNWEz7XE");
                image = ImageIO.read(url);
              //  System.out.print(url);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println("Ongeldige URL");
                e.printStackTrace();
        }
        this.view.setImage(image);
        this.view.repaint();
    } //method end

    class ListenerOfActions implements ActionListener {
        int selected = 0;
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            String actionCommand = e.getActionCommand();
            if(actionCommand.equals("OK")) {
               // int selected = view.getRouteComboBox().getSelectedIndex() + 1;
               // System.out.println(selected);
                System.out.println("This doesn't print");

             //   updateMap(selected);
            }
            System.out.println("and even outside the if statement, this doesn't print");

        }

        public int getSelected(){
            return this.selected;
        }


    } //class end
} //class end
```

My Model:

```
package main.java.models;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import main.java.controllers.MapController;
import main.resources.ConnectionManager;

import javax.swing.*;

public class MapModel {
    List<String> coordinateList = new ArrayList<String>(); //deze moet naar fillCoordinateListArray

    public List<String> fillCoordinateListArray(int selected){
        try (Connection connection = ConnectionManager.getConnection()) {
            String query = "SELECT RouteLocationID, RouteLocations.RouteID, X, Y FROM RouteLocations WHERE RouteID = ?";
            PreparedStatement stmt = connection.prepareStatement(query);
            stmt.setInt(1, selected);
            ResultSet results = stmt.executeQuery();

            while (results.next()) {
                double X = results.getDouble(3);
                double Y = results.getDouble(4);
                coordinateList.add(X + "," + Y);
            }

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println("Er is een fout opgetreden.");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return coordinateList;
    } //method end

    public String parseCoordinates(){
        String text = "";
        for(int i = 0; i<coordinateList.size(); i++) {
            text+="&markers=label:" + (i+1) + "%7C" + coordinateList.get(i) + "%7C";

        }
        return text;
    } //method end

    public ArrayList getAllRoutes(){
        ArrayList<String> routeArrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
        try (Connection connection = ConnectionManager.getConnection()) {
            String query = "SELECT RouteID, RouteName FROM route";
            PreparedStatement stmt = connection.prepareStatement(query);
            ResultSet results = stmt.executeQuery();

            while (results.next()) {
                String routeName = results.getString(2);
                routeArrayList.add(routeName);

            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println("Er is een fout opgetreden.");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println(routeArrayList);
        return routeArrayList;
    } //method end


} //class end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of right now, your code doesn't actually reference your `ListenerOfActions` class. If you move your `ListenerOfActions` class into your `MapView` class, you can properly add it as an action listener to your `jbOK` button.

```
ListenerOfActions listener = new ListenerOfActions();
jbOK.addActionListener(listener);
```

OR

```
jbOK.addActionListener(new ListenerOfActions());
```

Comment: I understand that placing it in the view would be easier, but what if I absolutely had to keep the ActionListener in the Controller? The ListenerOfActions class could be removed it doesn't matter to me

Comment: @DeZaakVanDeP You're falling in to a common trap - ask your self the simple question of - "why does the controller need to know how the view is implemented?" - the answer is, it doesn't and shouldn't.  Instead, the view and the controller should establish a contract between each other to state how data is passed between them, this way, you could use any view which implemented this contract.  Start with a `interface` which describes the information which the view expects the controller to pass to it (model data) and the events the controller can subscribe to from the view

Comment: @DeZaakVanDeP For a much longer discussion of the problem, you could have a look at this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26517856/java-and-gui-where-do-actionlisteners-belong-according-to-mvc-pattern/26518274#26518274) - Also remember, Swing is already a form of MVC, so you might find yourself fighting with the system